# Magento 2 - New custom URL for custom checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to create new checkout page with new url and need to show my custom address fields in that custom checkout page.

My way is :

1. Create new custom checkout module ( CustomCheckout )
2. Create new route ( like custom-checkout )
3. Copy and paste the checkout_index_index.xm layout in my custom
   checkout module

**Is that correct way ? pls give a solution ?**

/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mymodule_CustomCheckout" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="customcheckout" frontName="customcheckout">
            <module name="Mymodule_CustomCheckout"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Controller/Index/Index.php

```
namespace Mymodule\CustomCheckout\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        //$this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

/view/frontend/layout/customcheckout_index_index.xml

//Copy and paste checkout_index_index.xml from magento-checkout module

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by simply add before attribute in module tag.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="checkout" frontName="checkout">
        <module name="Mymodule_CustomCheckout" before="Magento_Checkout"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

so magento then call your custom checkout route instead of core checkout controller.
so accordingly you can change the layout and all.

Comment: need to replicate custom-checkout  as checkout page

Comment: it should be two different pages with same working functionalities